# Why does my CPU have a much higher speed than it's core speed of 1.6GHz?

Tags: windows, cpu, cpu-speed

My CPU, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U @1.6GHz averages around 2k GHz and I'm pretty sure the CPU is unclock-able. Why?

[image: Screenshot in Task Manager]

Comment: The screenshot shows that your base speed is actually 1.8Ghz. So even though you have a CPU that normally would be clocked at 1.6Ghz, it is already overclocked to 1.8Ghz. In addition, it turbo boosts to an even higher clock speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Intel Ark - [Intel® Core™ i5-8250U Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124967/intel-core-i5-8250u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html)

> Processor Base Frequency
>   1.60 GHz
>   Max Turbo Frequency
>   3.40 GHz
>
> **Processor Base Frequency**
>   Processor Base Frequency describes the rate
>   at which the processor's transistors open and close. The processor
>   base frequency is the operating point where TDP is defined. Frequency
>   is typically measured in gigahertz (GHz), or billion cycles per
>   second.
>
> **Max Turbo Frequency**
>   Max turbo frequency is the maximum single core frequency at which the processor is capable of operating using Intel® Turbo Boost Technology and, if present, Intel® Thermal Velocity Boost. Frequency is typically measured in gigahertz (GHz), or billion cycles per second.

Comment: Thanks so much. Only thought Intel processors with K in the ending can only be overclocked.

Answer (score 1):

Base frequency is 1.6GHz, but it can run at 3.4Ghz in Turbo. See the datasheet here

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124967/intel-core-i5-8250u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html

> Max turbo frequency is the maximum single-core frequency at which the processor is capable of operating using Intel® Turbo Boost Technology and, if present, Intel® Thermal Velocity Boost.

Comment: And in addition, the screenshot also shows its overclocked to 1.8Ghz.

Comment: turbo is 3.4 not 3.6